# Can we perform an action on the element selected by the 'not selector' in jQuery

Tags: jquery

There's this simple thing i want to do.

I have to add a **current** class to the first `<li>` element and **disabled** class to others.
 Currently i'm doing it this way:

`$('#slideshow li:first').addClass('current');`

`$('#slideshow li').not(':first').addClass('disabled');`

but i was wondering if we could di it in one line doing something like this:

`$('#slideshow li').not(':first', function(){ $(this).addClass('current'); }).addClass('disabled');`

Any enlightenment would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: Who said one line is the best...? efficient doesn't mean spare lines of code.

Comment: Yeah, i know that, and i quote, **"i was wondering"** :)

Comment: `addClass` takes a function as the first argument. Just use index to see if it the first and then return eater "current" or "disabled"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery chaining works because the method called is returning the same, or modified, result set that you're running it on. So by filtering with `not()` you're returning the modified result set and won't have access the original one again.

You work around this by using `.end()`, which does the following:

`End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.`

So either you do something like you're doing (but with caching the result set), which I find a tad less confusing, and more readable:

```
var elements = $('#slideshow li');
elements.first().addClass('current');
elements.not(':first').addClass('disabled');
```

Or you do it in one line, using `end()`, which can potentially turn into a really long line of code:

```
$('#slideshow li').first().addClass('current').end().not(':first').addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick explaination Joakim. I guess i'll stick to this then! :)

Answer (score 2):

Best I can do early in the morning...

```
$('#slideshow li').first().addClass('current').end().not(':first').addClass('disabled');
```

Comment: Yeah, I too tried this. So i guess this is the best way to do it!!
Like if i want to do a little complex stuff to the first `<li>` i have to use another line, no function can be called there?

Comment: Check out Andreas's answer for a better one liner that doesn't involve traversing the stack.

Answer (score 2):

you can say:

```
$('#slideshow li').addClass(function(i) { return !i ? "current" : "disabled"; });
```

`i` is 0-indexed and is the index of where in your selection the element is.

So if `i == 0` is the same as the first element

`i == 0 == false == !true`.

So:

`!i == !0 == !false == true`.

then we can return:

`return !i ? "current" : "disabled"`.

Means:

```
if ( !i ) {
    return "current";
}
else {
    return "disabled";
}
```

Comment: Best one-liner of all the answers.  Cheers

Comment: For the current situation, i have to say, this is the best possible answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

My advise is: Don't do it with one line. split it to two lines and cache the result of the selector:

```
var items = $('#slideshow li');
items.first().addClass('current');
items.not(':first').addClass('disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `siblings()` method:

```
$("#slideshow li:first").addClass("current").siblings().addClass("disabled");
```

Why didn't i think of this before????